# How to fix "Unknown qemu_device" building Android 13 for Car

Tags: android, android-source, android-automotive

I am building Android 13 Lunch 11 AOSP CAR X86_64. However, it fails at 98% with "unknown type qemu_device".

I am trying to build branches android-13.0.0_r74, and would need your guidance to figure out how to get around this build issue.

Also, If somebody as some advice on AOSP, how to select branch or find release notes for example.

Here is the build log:

```
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:209: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
build/make/core/soong_config.mk:210: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=13
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_car_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.2.0-26-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-22.04.3-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=TQ3A.230605.012
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/generic/goldfish device/generic/goldfish-opengl hardware/google/camera hardware/google/camera/devices/EmulatedCamera
============================================
build/make/core/build_id.mk was modified, regenerating...
build/make/core/version_defaults.mk was modified, regenerating...
[ 98% 1032/1048] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...
system/sepolicy/Android.mk:57: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
system/sepolicy/Android.mk:62: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
[  1% 1155/68889] //system/sepolicy:sepolicy_neverallows_vendor Neverallow check: sepolicy_neverallows_vendor
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy_neverallows_vendor/policy
out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy -M -c 30 -o out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy_neverallows_vendor/policy out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/sepolicy_neverallows_vendor.checkpolicy.conf/android_common/sepolicy_neverallows_vendor.
checkpolicy.conf # hash of input list: 15871fa7f1904c26cfc726ea362c19ede7f225bff09f1871b1f7d5657882753a
device/generic/car/emulator/usbpt/bluetooth/btusb/sepolicy/domain.te:2:ERROR 'unknown type qemu_device' at token ';' on line 78981:
allow domain qemu_device:chr_file { { getattr open read ioctl lock map watch watch_reads } { open append write lock map } };
#line 1 "device/generic/car/emulator/usbpt/bluetooth/btusb/sepolicy/domain.te"
checkpolicy:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
09:14:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (03:20 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I have tryed to build r74 and r69, to see if it might be a regression. without success. I have searched on google but could not find any relevant information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Same error here. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Very similar error I have got, while building for RMX1851. Any solutions?

Comment: @HuckQC any update on this issue? got the same error for Car Android 13

Answer (score 0):

like you, I too encountered issues while trying to build the target product "aosp_car_arm64-userdebug". However, upon trying "sdk_car_arm64_userdebug", it worked successfully. I am hopeful that this serves as a practical solution.